# Form input fields that do not clear UNLESS in debug mode

Tags: javascript, html, forms

This is curious, I think.
I have 2 input field in a simple form (here simplified):

```js
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#user").val('');
    $("#psw").val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form  id="entry" method="POST">  
 <div class="row">       
  <div class="large-6 columns">
    <label>User</label>
    <input id="user" type="text" value="">
  </div>
    
  <div class="large-6 columns">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input id="psw" type="password" value="">
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

These are supposed to clear the fields on page loading. Actually they do not and I see the previous content in the user field.

The funny thing is that if I open a debug window to see what's happening, they are regularly cleared.

I put the two rows twice, just to enforce them, both at the beginning of the JS section and inside the `$(document).ready(function() {...

I also copied a suggestion from an answer to clear the cache in the page Head, again without result:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Additionally (this is a collateral issue) then following method taken from other answers:

```
document.getElementById("entry").reset();
```

raises a 'reset is an undefined function' error.

I use jquery-2.2.4.min.js

`

Comment: *In the JS section, I have: [...] These are supposed to clear the fields on page loading* -> make sure you put this code after the page has loaded, for example inside a [`$(document).ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) callback

Comment: are you duplicating id's? second error suggests you aren't getting a HTMLFormElement.

Comment: Why do you need this at all? The inputs already have `value=""`, so they shouldn't be prefilled. Are you using the Back button to reload the page? That doesn't always re-run JavaScript.

Comment: For Filiu: I know they are supposed to clear fields, but they do not; this is the reason for my question. The code is, also, within the document.ready function.

Comment: ...continue. For Filiu: I know they are supposed to clear fields, but they do not; this is the reason for my question. The code is within the document.ready function too.  For  Orangesandlemons: there are not any duplicated ID.  For  Barmar: again, this is what is supposed to be. I reaload the page with the correct button (Ctrl-R). If it can help, this is my testing page URL: https://cina.boxidee.it/test.html Pls try yourself to see if you get the same result. Note: I use Firefox 64.0 (32bit) with Win7

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**
The issue is not related to programming, but to the browser's options.
I had the 'store password' option enabled and possibly I accepted to save the credentials, I do not recall it.  Disabling the option or setting 'never remember password for this site' fixes the problem, but it requires an end user intervent.

Despite of it, the behaviour is still unclear to me for these points:
1. Apparently the browser fills the fields AFTER the page is loaded and AFTER the JS functions are executed. Is it normal ?
2. During the debugging session the filling is possibly disabled at all since the fields remain empty.

Anyway, since these points relate to Mozilla, I consider them O.T.

I still have to find out why the form.reset raises the error, but I think this is something I could figure out myself.